# Z-index issue : Stack a child element behind a parent container

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where in there are 2 children in a parent container. The first child occupies the entire content of the parent container.
The other child should be below the parent container. Currently it shows up on top of the parent. I am struggling to stack the 2nd child element behind the parent container.

Is it possible to do so. If so how do I approach the solution.

**Note:** I cannot get rid of the `z-index` of the parent container as it is the modal in this case

**HTML**

```
 <div class="parent">
    <h1>Parent</h1>
      <code>position: absolute;<br/>
      z-index: 1;</code>

    <div class="outer-child">
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <h1>Outer Child</h1>
        <code>position: relative;<br/>
        z-index: 1;</code>
    </div>

    <div class="child">

        <h1>Child</h1>
        <code>position: absolute;<br/>
        z-index: -1;</code>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 html {
    padding: 20px;
    font: 12px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
}

div {
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: relative;
}

.parent {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 330px;
    border: 1px dashed #900;
    background-color: #fdd;
    padding: 40px 20px 20px;
    height: 200px;
}

.child {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 260px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 110px;
    border: 1px dashed #009;
    padding-top: 125px;
    background-color: #ddf;
    text-align: center;
}

.outer-child {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 330px;
    border: 1px dashed #900;
    background-color: #ffc;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3269rjqh/2/)**

Comment: reorganize your HTML to keep your div separate. That will help. something like this <div -parent></div><div -child></div>

Comment: @Ananthaprakash Cannot reorganize the `HTML` since the content is part of the modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the parent element `z-index` to `initial`

```
html {
    padding: 20px;
    font: 12px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
}

div {
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: relative;
}

.parent {
    z-index: initial;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 330px;
    border: 1px dashed #900;
    background-color: #fdd;
    padding: 40px 20px 20px;
    height: 200px;
}

.child {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 260px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 110px;
    border: 1px dashed #009;
    padding-top: 125px;
    background-color: #ddf;
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3269rjqh/1/

Comment: That is correct. Looks like I forgot to add one more usecase, where in the the parent is in reality a modal and I cannot remove the `z-index` since it has to be stacked above the page

Comment: Yeah, would have been helpful to know.  It gets more complicated, but ideally wrapping these elements in an element with a position: relative should work, try updating your fiddle with the actual example

Comment: I reality I tried even that approach and it did not work. The use case that I have provided here is a minimalistic subset of the original problem. But it did not help

Comment: Try updating your fiddle with the actual example so I can  test fixes instead of guessing

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Wrapping the `modal` container `(z-index: initial)` with another element and setting the z-index to it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Once an element has a z-index, it creates new plane, so any child elements with a z-index are always going to be "above" it (in the z-plane). You can either remove the z-index from the parent, or restructure your HTML accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
    padding: 20px;
    font: 12px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
}

div {
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: relative;
}

.parent {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 330px;
    border: 1px dashed #900;
    background-color: #fdd;
    padding: 40px 20px 20px;
    height: 200px;
}

.child {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 260px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 110px;
    border: 1px dashed #009;
    padding-top: 125px;
    background-color: #ddf;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h1>Parent</h1>
      <code>position: absolute;<br/>
      z-index: 1;</code>
</div>
<div class="child">
        <h1>Child</h1>
        <code>position: absolute;<br/>
        z-index: -1;</code>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a pretty trivial solution. It gets tricky since I cannot reorganize the HTML since it is a modal.